How to Dynamically Populate start_date in ServiceNow Change Request Creation?
I have a GitHub Actions workflow with a bunch of jobs, including a ServiceNow Change Request Creation process. In the ServiceNow Change Request JSON payload, there's a field called start_date that needs to be populated with the current UTC time. However, I'm currently setting this field manually, which is not ideal.
Here's a snippet of my workflow:
Snow-Change-Creation:
  name: Snow-Change-Creation
  needs: [Previous Job Name]
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
    - name: ServiceNow Change Request Creation
      uses: ServiceNow/servicenow-devops-change@v3.1.0
      with:
        devops-integration-token: ${{ secrets.SN_..._TOKEN }}
        instance-url: ${{ secrets.SN_..._INSTANCE_URL }}
        tool-id: ${{ secrets.SN_..._TOOL_ID }}
        context-github: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        job-name: 'Snow-Change-Creation'
        change-request: '{
                          "setCloseCode":"true",
                          "autoCloseChange":"true",
                          "attributes":{
                                          ...
                                          "start_date": "2024-04-05 06:28:00"
                                         }
                        }'

As you can see, the start_date field is currently hard-coded. I'm looking for a way to dynamically populate this field with the current UTC time whenever the workflow runs, ideally start of workflow trigger.
I've tried using github.run_started_at didn't work.
I also have tried the following:
 change-request: '{
                          "setCloseCode":"true",
                          "autoCloseChange":"true",
                          "attributes":{
                                          ...
                                          "start_date": "needs.previous-job.outputs.<output-name>"
                                         }
                        }'

Which this part needs.previous-job.outputs.<output-name> has be created in previous job and stored as github output:
    .previous-job:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        # outputs to share with other jobs
        outputs:
            output-name: ${{ steps.get_utctime.outputs.time_output }}

          - id: get_utctime
            run: echo "time_output=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Could someone please suggest a reliable method or workaround to achieve this?

Hi @mas could you please let me know, how did you fetch the tool_id details from servicenow? I have the url, username and password but not sure of tool_id

Our DevSecOps team did that part and we stored in github secret, can any of these docs help you? https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/washingtondc-devops/page/product/enterprise-dev-ops/concept/github-integration-dev-ops.html
